# Store JSON Object from multiple input groups

Tags: arrays, json, loops, input

**NOTE:** A working solution was provided below; however, Array.map... does not work in IE. I need a solution that also works in IE.
**Original Post:**
I have a dynamic input group (can add and remove groups). 
Each input group has a state select and a textbox.

I want to loop through the inputs on a keyup/change event and store the values in a key value pair like so: 
licGroupObj = [ 
{ "licState": "WA", "licNum": "111" },

 { "licState": "OR", "licNum": "222" },

{ "licState": "CA", "licNum": "333" }]

I have tried the following, but it does not work. I need to add a loop somewhere.

```js
 $('body').on('change keyup', '.license_state, .license_input', function () {
               
                var licGroupObj = {};
                licGroupObj = $('.license_group').map(function () {
                    var licState = $('.license_state').val();
                    var licNum = $('.license_input').val();
                    return { licState, licNum } ;
                }).get();

                
                $('#InputForLicenseObject').val('');
                $('#InputForLicenseObject').val(JSON.stringify(licGroupObj));
            });
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #222 !important;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem !important;
}

legend {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-2px, -20px);
  background: #fff;
  width: unset !important;
  font-size: 0.85rem !important;
}

.form-select {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.license_group .btn {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <main class="container py-3">
       <label>Store Input Values</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="License Object" aria-label="License Number" id="InputForLicenseObject" />

        <fieldset id="buildlicenseform" class="my-3">
            <legend>License Group</legend>
            <div class="input-group my-3 license_group">
                <span>
                    <select name="LicenseState" class="form-select license_state" aria-label="License State" required="">
                        <option selected="">State</option>
                        <option value="AL">AL</option>
                        <option value="AK">AK</option>
                        <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                        <option value="AR">AR</option>
                        <option value="CA">CA</option>
                        <option value="CO">CO</option>
                        <option value="CT">CT</option>
                        <option value="DE">DE</option>
                        <option value="DC">DC</option>
                        <option value="FL">FL</option>
                        <option value="GA">GA</option>
                        <option value="HI">HI</option>
                        <option value="ID">ID</option>
                        <option value="IL">IL</option>
                        <option value="IN">IN</option>
                        <option value="IA">IA</option>
                        <option value="KS">KS</option>
                        <option value="KY">KY</option>
                        <option value="LA">LA</option>
                        <option value="ME">ME</option>
                        <option value="MD">MD</option>
                        <option value="MA">MA</option>
                        <option value="MI">MI</option>
                        <option value="MN">MN</option>
                        <option value="MS">MS</option>
                        <option value="MO">MO</option>
                        <option value="MT">MT</option>
                        <option value="NE">NE</option>
                        <option value="NV">NV</option>
                        <option value="NH">NH</option>
                        <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                        <option value="NM">NM</option>
                        <option value="NY">NY</option>
                        <option value="NC">NC</option>
                        <option value="ND">ND</option>
                        <option value="OH">OH</option>
                        <option value="OK">OK</option>
                        <option value="OR">OR</option>
                        <option value="PA">PA</option>
                        <option value="RI">RI</option>
                        <option value="SC">SC</option>
                        <option value="SD">SD</option>
                        <option value="TN">TN</option>
                        <option value="TX">TX</option>
                        <option value="UT">UT</option>
                        <option value="VT">VT</option>
                        <option value="VA">VA</option>
                        <option value="WA">WA</option>
                        <option value="WV">WV</option>
                        <option value="WI">WI</option>
                        <option value="WY">WY</option>
                    </select>
                </span>
                <input type="text" name="LicenseInput" class="form-control license_input" placeholder="License Number" aria-label="License Number">
                <button class="btn btn-light border add_remove_license_button remove_license_button">
                    <i class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill"></i>
                </button>
            </div><div class="input-group my-3 license_group"><span><select name="LicenseState" class="form-select license_state" aria-label="License State"><option selected="">State</option><option value="AL">AL</option><option value="AK">AK</option><option value="AZ">AZ</option><option value="AR">AR</option><option value="CA">CA</option><option value="CO">CO</option><option value="CT">CT</option><option value="DE">DE</option><option value="DC">DC</option><option value="FL">FL</option><option value="GA">GA</option><option value="HI">HI</option><option value="ID">ID</option><option value="IL">IL</option><option value="IN">IN</option><option value="IA">IA</option><option value="KS">KS</option><option value="KY">KY</option><option value="LA">LA</option><option value="ME">ME</option><option value="MD">MD</option><option value="MA">MA</option><option value="MI">MI</option><option value="MN">MN</option><option value="MS">MS</option><option value="MO">MO</option><option value="MT">MT</option><option value="NE">NE</option><option value="NV">NV</option><option value="NH">NH</option><option value="NJ">NJ</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="NY">NY</option><option value="NC">NC</option><option value="ND">ND</option><option value="OH">OH</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="OR">OR</option><option value="PA">PA</option><option value="RI">RI</option><option value="SC">SC</option><option value="SD">SD</option><option value="TN">TN</option><option value="TX">TX</option><option value="UT">UT</option><option value="VT">VT</option><option value="VA">VA</option><option value="WA">WA</option><option value="WV">WV</option><option value="WI">WI</option><option value="WY">WY</option></select></span><input type="text" name="LicenseInput" class="form-control license_input" placeholder="License Number" aria-label="License Number"><button class="btn btn-light border add_remove_license_button remove_license_button"><i class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill"></i></button></div><div class="input-group my-3 license_group"><span><select name="LicenseState" class="form-select license_state" aria-label="License State"><option selected="">State</option><option value="AL">AL</option><option value="AK">AK</option><option value="AZ">AZ</option><option value="AR">AR</option><option value="CA">CA</option><option value="CO">CO</option><option value="CT">CT</option><option value="DE">DE</option><option value="DC">DC</option><option value="FL">FL</option><option value="GA">GA</option><option value="HI">HI</option><option value="ID">ID</option><option value="IL">IL</option><option value="IN">IN</option><option value="IA">IA</option><option value="KS">KS</option><option value="KY">KY</option><option value="LA">LA</option><option value="ME">ME</option><option value="MD">MD</option><option value="MA">MA</option><option value="MI">MI</option><option value="MN">MN</option><option value="MS">MS</option><option value="MO">MO</option><option value="MT">MT</option><option value="NE">NE</option><option value="NV">NV</option><option value="NH">NH</option><option value="NJ">NJ</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="NY">NY</option><option value="NC">NC</option><option value="ND">ND</option><option value="OH">OH</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="OR">OR</option><option value="PA">PA</option><option value="RI">RI</option><option value="SC">SC</option><option value="SD">SD</option><option value="TN">TN</option><option value="TX">TX</option><option value="UT">UT</option><option value="VT">VT</option><option value="VA">VA</option><option value="WA">WA</option><option value="WV">WV</option><option value="WI">WI</option><option value="WY">WY</option></select></span><input type="text" name="LicenseInput" class="form-control license_input" placeholder="License Number" aria-label="License Number"><button class="btn btn-light border add_remove_license_button remove_license_button"><i class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill"></i></button></div>
        </fieldset>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` is a loop. Because you use `$('.license_state').val()` and `$('.license_input').val()`, it only get the first element found. Instead, inside callback of map, you should include index & element and use selector inside of element parameter. Also, I don't recommend use `keyup` event in this situation, it fire even when user press `ctr` which doesn't affect input, `input` event is better

```js
$('body').on('change input', '.license_state, .license_input', function () {
    var licGroupObj = {};
    licGroupObj = $('.license_group').map(function (idx, ele) {
        var licState = $(ele).find('.license_state').val();
        var licNum = $(ele).find('.license_input').val();
        return { licState, licNum };
    }).get();

    $('#InputForLicenseObject').val('');
    $('#InputForLicenseObject').val(JSON.stringify(licGroupObj));
});
```

```css
fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #222 !important;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
    padding: 0.5rem 1rem 1rem 1rem !important;
}

legend {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-2px, -20px);
    background: #fff;
    width: unset !important;
    font-size: 0.85rem !important;
}

.form-select {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.license_group .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<main class="container py-3">
    <label>Store Input Values</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="License Object" aria-label="License Number"
        id="InputForLicenseObject" />

    <fieldset id="buildlicenseform" class="my-3">
        <legend>License Group</legend>
        <div class="input-group my-3 license_group">
            <span>
                <select name="LicenseState" class="form-select license_state" aria-label="License State"
                    required="">
                    <option selected="">State</option>
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="AK">AK</option>
                    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                    <option value="AR">AR</option>
                    <option value="CA">CA</option>
                    <option value="CO">CO</option>
                    <option value="CT">CT</option>
                    <option value="DE">DE</option>
                    <option value="DC">DC</option>
                    <option value="FL">FL</option>
                    <option value="GA">GA</option>
                    <option value="HI">HI</option>
                    <option value="ID">ID</option>
                    <option value="IL">IL</option>
                    <option value="IN">IN</option>
                    <option value="IA">IA</option>
                    <option value="KS">KS</option>
                    <option value="KY">KY</option>
                    <option value="LA">LA</option>
                    <option value="ME">ME</option>
                    <option value="MD">MD</option>
                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                    <option value="MI">MI</option>
                    <option value="MN">MN</option>
                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    <option value="MO">MO</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                    <option value="NE">NE</option>
                    <option value="NV">NV</option>
                    <option value="NH">NH</option>
                    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                    <option value="NM">NM</option>
                    <option value="NY">NY</option>
                    <option value="NC">NC</option>
                    <option value="ND">ND</option>
                    <option value="OH">OH</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                    <option value="RI">RI</option>
                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                    <option value="SD">SD</option>
                    <option value="TN">TN</option>
                    <option value="TX">TX</option>
                    <option value="UT">UT</option>
                    <option value="VT">VT</option>
                    <option value="VA">VA</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                    <option value="WV">WV</option>
                    <option value="WI">WI</option>
                    <option value="WY">WY</option>
                </select>
            </span>
            <input type="text" name="LicenseInput" class="form-control license_input" placeholder="License Number"
                aria-label="License Number">
            <button class="btn btn-light border add_remove_license_button remove_license_button">
                <i class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group my-3 license_group">
            <span>
                <select name="LicenseState"
                    class="form-select license_state" aria-label="License State">
                    <option selected="">State</option>
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="AK">AK</option>
                    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                    <option value="AR">AR</option>
                    <option value="CA">CA</option>
                    <option value="CO">CO</option>
                    <option value="CT">CT</option>
                    <option value="DE">DE</option>
                    <option value="DC">DC</option>
                    <option value="FL">FL</option>
                    <option value="GA">GA</option>
                    <option value="HI">HI</option>
                    <option value="ID">ID</option>
                    <option value="IL">IL</option>
                    <option value="IN">IN</option>
                    <option value="IA">IA</option>
                    <option value="KS">KS</option>
                    <option value="KY">KY</option>
                    <option value="LA">LA</option>
                    <option value="ME">ME</option>
                    <option value="MD">MD</option>
                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                    <option value="MI">MI</option>
                    <option value="MN">MN</option>
                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    <option value="MO">MO</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                    <option value="NE">NE</option>
                    <option value="NV">NV</option>
                    <option value="NH">NH</option>
                    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                    <option value="NM">NM</option>
                    <option value="NY">NY</option>
                    <option value="NC">NC</option>
                    <option value="ND">ND</option>
                    <option value="OH">OH</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                    <option value="RI">RI</option>
                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                    <option value="SD">SD</option>
                    <option value="TN">TN</option>
                    <option value="TX">TX</option>
                    <option value="UT">UT</option>
                    <option value="VT">VT</option>
                    <option value="VA">VA</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                    <option value="WV">WV</option>
                    <option value="WI">WI</option>
                    <option value="WY">WY</option>
                </select></span><input type="text" name="LicenseInput" class="form-control license_input"
                placeholder="License Number" aria-label="License Number"><button
                class="btn btn-light border add_remove_license_button remove_license_button"><i
                    class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill"></i></button></div>
        <div class="input-group my-3 license_group">
            <span>
                <select name="LicenseState"
                    class="form-select license_state" aria-label="License State">
                    <option selected="">State</option>
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="AK">AK</option>
                    <option value="AZ">AZ</option>
                    <option value="AR">AR</option>
                    <option value="CA">CA</option>
                    <option value="CO">CO</option>
                    <option value="CT">CT</option>
                    <option value="DE">DE</option>
                    <option value="DC">DC</option>
                    <option value="FL">FL</option>
                    <option value="GA">GA</option>
                    <option value="HI">HI</option>
                    <option value="ID">ID</option>
                    <option value="IL">IL</option>
                    <option value="IN">IN</option>
                    <option value="IA">IA</option>
                    <option value="KS">KS</option>
                    <option value="KY">KY</option>
                    <option value="LA">LA</option>
                    <option value="ME">ME</option>
                    <option value="MD">MD</option>
                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                    <option value="MI">MI</option>
                    <option value="MN">MN</option>
                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    <option value="MO">MO</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                    <option value="NE">NE</option>
                    <option value="NV">NV</option>
                    <option value="NH">NH</option>
                    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
                    <option value="NM">NM</option>
                    <option value="NY">NY</option>
                    <option value="NC">NC</option>
                    <option value="ND">ND</option>
                    <option value="OH">OH</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                    <option value="OR">OR</option>
                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                    <option value="RI">RI</option>
                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                    <option value="SD">SD</option>
                    <option value="TN">TN</option>
                    <option value="TX">TX</option>
                    <option value="UT">UT</option>
                    <option value="VT">VT</option>
                    <option value="VA">VA</option>
                    <option value="WA">WA</option>
                    <option value="WV">WV</option>
                    <option value="WI">WI</option>
                    <option value="WY">WY</option>
                </select></span><input type="text" name="LicenseInput" class="form-control license_input"
                placeholder="License Number" aria-label="License Number"><button
                class="btn btn-light border add_remove_license_button remove_license_button"><i
                    class="bi bi-dash-circle-fill"></i></button></div>
    </fieldset>
</main>
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Will also remove the keyup event and use input. :)

Comment: After testing in IE, Array.map is not supported. I need a way to loop and create the array of objects that also works in IE.

Comment: @AmyRuddy have you tried normal [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop? It's working fine for IE >= 3

Comment: Yes I was. Thanks for the reminder to post an update. The following works in IE and replaces the Array.map solution: 
licGroupObj = []; // Empty the License Objecte, then store new values
           
            let inputs = $('.license_group');

            for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

                let licState = $(inputs[i]).find('.license_state').val();

                let licNum = $(inputs[i]).find('.license_input').val();

                licGroupObj.push({ "licState": licState, "licNum": licNum });

Answer (score 0):

The first solution above using Array.map works great; however, it does not work in IE, but the following does. Also => functions needed to be replaced as well as .contains(), none supported in IE.

```
licGroupObj = []; // Empty the License Objecte, then store new values
       
        let inputs = $('.license_group');

        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

            let licState = $(inputs[i]).find('.license_state').val();

            let licNum = $(inputs[i]).find('.license_input').val();

            licGroupObj.push({ "licState": licState, "licNum": licNum });
```

..

```
//Does not work in IE
    // var result = licGroupObj.filter(obj => obj.licNum !== '');

// Works in IE
       var result = licGroupObj.filter(function (obj) {return obj.licNum !== ''; });

//insted of .contains with indexOf:
// does not contain [{
    if (licVal.length > 0 && licVal.indexOf(regex) == -1) { 
    if (licVal.indexOf(regex) >= 0) {
```